# How to disable the button

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I want to deactivate the button6 if the retrieved date is less than the current date, I have used the below code for this, but it is not working. Please help me to find the error.

```
protected void Button6_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=e-learningsystem; uid=root; password=123;port=3307;");
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Date FROM fundamentals of is WHERE ChapNo=Chapter 1", connection);
        string date = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        //date = cmd;
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(cmd).CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now) < 0)
        {
            DownLoadFileFromServer("~/NewFolder1/" + "Fundamentals of IS.pdf");
        }
        else
        {
            Button6.Enabled = false;
        }
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // file IO errors

    }
}
```

This the `serverMapPath` code

```
public static string ServerMapPath(string path)
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);
}

public static HttpResponse GetHttpResponse()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Response;
}
public static void DownLoadFileFromServer(string fileName)
{
    //This is used to get Project Location.
    try
    {
        string filePath = ServerMapPath(fileName);
        //This is used to get the current response.
        HttpResponse res = GetHttpResponse();
        res.Clear();
        res.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filePath);
        res.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        res.WriteFile(filePath);
        res.Flush();
        res.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the Button Click is were you want to disable the button?  Would it not be on page load you want to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to disable the button that was just clicked?

Comment: @oGJo, for example to prevent other clicks, until action was finished?!

Comment: What are you getting as output. does your code runs successfully but button is not disabled or are you getting any error???

Comment: you are most likely getting an exception that is swallowed by <code>catch(Excpetion ex){}</code>... Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

MSDN Answer:

I thought this will help you

```
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);

string relationship;
if (result < 0)
   relationship = "is earlier than";
else if (result == 0)
   relationship = "is the same time as";         
else
   relationship = "is later than";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Date FROM fundamentals of is WHERE ChapNo=Chapter 1", connection);
string date = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
//date = cmd;
if (Convert.ToDateTime(cmd).CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now) < 0)
```

Are you sure going to `Convert.ToDateTime(cmd)`?

Didn't you want to `Convert.ToDateTime(date)`?

Comment: this also nt wrking
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Date FROM fundamentals of is WHERE ChapNo=Chapter 1", connection);
                string date = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(date).CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now) < 0)
                {
                    DownLoadFileFromServer("~/NewFolder1/" + "Fundamentals of IS.pdf");
                }

Comment: And what values do you have in `date` and in `Convert.ToDateTime(date)` ?

Comment: date is the value saved in DB Convert.ToDateTime(date) has the string value of it

Comment: And `Convert.ToDateTime(date).CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now)` > 0 ? You want to tell, that `Button6.Enabled = false;` executed, but button still enabled?

Comment: If you told us, that `date is the value saved in DB` so looks like it works for you, other way you lied us

Comment: maybe nothing is working? not just the part pertaining to disabling the button

Comment: I won't wonder if there is an error `SQL: Client unable to establish connection`

Answer (score 0):

The following line may have a logical error, as you are converting the `cmd` variable to a `DateTime` instead of the `date` that is returned by your command:

```
  if (Convert.ToDateTime(cmd).CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now) < 0)
```

Using this instead may solve your problem:

```
  if (Convert.ToDateTime(date).CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now) < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deactivate the button when the retrieved date is less than the current date, you should invert your if statement condition, and use the `date` string instead of `cmd` :

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(cmd).CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now) < 0)
```

to

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(date).CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now) >= 0)
```

so you can download the file to server if the date is higher or equal than the current date, and disable the button if the date is less than the current date.

Or just invert the whole if :

```
    if (Convert.ToDateTime(date).CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now) < 0)
    {
        Button6.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        DownLoadFileFromServer("~/NewFolder1/" + "Fundamentals of IS.pdf");
    }
```

Comment: Is this correct???? 
"SELECT DATE FROM fundamentals of IS WHERE ChapNo=Chapter 1"

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to convert the `date`:

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(date).CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now) < 0)
```

it would be throwing an exception every time you hit that line.

Answer (score 0):

One option is disable it in javascript(in on click event)
another option is to write the same code in Page_Onload(and checking ISPostback)

Answer (score 0):

Well, besides the obvious problem that everyone mentioned `if (Convert.ToDateTime(cmd).CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now) < 0) //need to use date instead of cmd`, the code contains an anti-pattern which is using overly general `catch` blocks.

The code is catching an Exception to handle IO exceptions. But what if there are other kinds of exceptions? I am starting to suspect that for some reason `Convert.ToDateTime` is throwing an error that is swallowed by the catch statement that you think is catching *only* IO exceptions. It will, in fact, catch any kind of exception including a possible `FormatException` which could be thrown by a call to `Convert.ToDateTime`.

But it might be a `SqlException` as I explain next:

There is also invalid SQL in this line:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = 
    new MySqlCommand("SELECT Date FROM fundamentals of is WHERE ChapNo=Chapter 1",
    connection);
```

I think it should be:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = 
    new MySqlCommand("Select Date from fundamentals where ChapNo='Chapter 1'",
    connection); //that is, if ChapNo is a STRING/TEXT!
```

executing this command will throw an error that you will not be able to detect because of your catch statement. You need to make your catch statements as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have `Button6.Enabled = false;` inside a try catch where you do not `throw an Exception`. Try to copy it up in top of your method, like shown below, to see if it is working:

```
protected void Button6_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button6.Enabled = false;
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;     ..
..
}
```

if it works, then find the error in your statements inside the try catch.

Also doublecheck your `aspx code`. Maybe you are referencing a method called `Button6_Click` and not as posted `Button6_Click1` (maybe a copy of Button6_Click)